# Array of images from flickr not showing in the intended order

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

*I'd like to preface I'm a total beginner with JS, only been working with it for a few days now.*

---

Here's what I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/joyroyxw/

What I want to do is get a person's name and display images of each letter in their name.
So far I'm able to split the name into the individual letters, and concatenate "letter," as search tags, so that flickr returns images of each letter.

My problem is these images are not being added in order, could this be because one query loads faster than another?  How could I add a buffer or delay so that each letter is displayed in order? Why would it do that if my for loop is sending the tags to the function in order?

---

Javascript from jsfiddle:

```
function getQueryStringVar(name){
    var qs = window.location.search.slice(1);
    var props = qs.split("&");
    for (var i=0 ; i < props.length;i++){
        var pair = props[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] === name) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function getLetterImage(tag){

var flickerAPI = "https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

            $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
                tags: tag,
                tagmode: "all",
                format: "json"
            })
            .done(function (flickrdata) {
                //console.log(flickrdata);
                var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * flickrdata.items.length);
                var item = flickrdata.items[i];
                var url = item.media.m;
                console.log(url);
                $("body").append("<img src="+ url + "></img>");
                });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
        var name = getQueryStringVar("name") || "Derek";

            var str = "letter,";
            var searchtags = new Array()
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                //console.log(str.concat(searchtags.charAt(i)));
                searchtags[i] = str.concat(name.charAt(i));
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++){
            //getLetterImage(searchtags[j]);
            getLetterImage(searchtags[j]);
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using append, try having a place holder element already build to receive the data.

```
<div id="img1">Loading</div>
<div id="img2">Loading</div>
<div id="img3">Loading</div>
```

You can dynamically create the elements as needed with javascript.  Then you populate them in the order.  Simply increment i as you go.

```
$("#img"+i).html("<img src="+ url + "></img>");
```

**UPDATE**

Your jsfiddle was very close, but you have to remember that ajax is asynchronous.

html

```
<body>
    <h1>Hi! What's your name?</h1>

    <form action="trending.html">
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="name">
    </form>

    <div id="img0">Loading</div>
    <div id="img1">Loading</div>
    <div id="img2">Loading</div>
    <div id="img3">Loading</div>
    <div id="img4">Loading</div>

  </body>
```

javascript

```
function getQueryStringVar(name){
    var qs = window.location.search.slice(1);
    var props = qs.split("&");
    for (var i=0 ; i < props.length;i++){
        var pair = props[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] === name) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function getLetterImage(tag, theNumber){

var flickerAPI = "https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

            return $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
                tags: tag,
                tagmode: "all",
                format: "json"
            })
            .then(function (flickrdata) {
                //console.log(flickrdata);
                var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * flickrdata.items.length);
                var item = flickrdata.items[i];
                var url = item.media.m;
                $("#img"+theNumber).html("<img src="+ url + "></img>");
                }); 
}



$(document).ready(function() {
        var name = getQueryStringVar("name") || "Derek Martin";

            var str = "letter,";
            var searchtags = new Array()
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                searchtags[i] = str.concat(name.charAt(i));
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++){
                getLetterImage(searchtags[j], j);

            }


});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I may have misinterpreted what you said :/ 
Here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/zjm3qvhd/